# Entity Framework Mysql Nested Property

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

i have this class structure. When i do some select i get an exception error.

```
public class A
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<B> B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int BId { get; set; }
    public virtual C C { get; set; }

    public int AId { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}

public class C // Manifiesto carga
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("B")]
    public int CId { get; set; }

    public virtual B B { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<D> D { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<E> E { get; set; }
}

public class D
{
    public int DId { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    public int CId { get; set; }
    public virtual C C { get; set; }
}

public class E
{
    public int EId { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    public int CId { get; set; }
    public virtual C C { get; set; }
}


    context.AA
                .Include(e => e.B.Select(s => s.C.D))
                .Include(e => e.B.Select(s => s.C.E)).FirstOrDefault(e => e.AId == 1);
```

Im lost, what can i do? or where im failing?

Thank you.

(sorry for my english)

[Image exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiCBQ.png)

In the picture above you can see the exception message.

Comment: what column do you remove?

Comment: does it help when you put the parent in `D` and `E` ? See answer

Comment: Please add the full error message to your question and use the real classes and table names.

Comment: `B` and 'C' are a 1-to-1 relation? have you tried the include without the select?

Comment: @RoelantM how can i do that? B is a collection. i cant do e.B.C

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem fixed when you also put the parent in `D` and `E`

```
public class D {
   public virtual C C {get;set;}
}
public class E {
   public virtual C C {get;set;}
}
```